# Accessing Self from Swift Closure

Tags: swift, closures, subclass, self, navigationcontroller

I am trying to call the method below that was declared in the `superclass` from its `subclass`. However, inside the method `self.navigationController` became `nil`. The **superclass's method** was called from a completion closure of a NSURLSession task in the subclass.

```
func showSuccessHUDwithMessage(msg: String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let successHud = MBProgressHUD(view: self.view)
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(successHud)

        successHud.mode = .CustomView
        successHud.customView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"37x-Checkmark"))
        successHud.labelText = msg
        successHud.show(true)
        successHud.hide(true, afterDelay: 1.0)
    }
}
```

When I check the value of self in `showSuccessHUDwithMessage:` I still get the subclass, but wasn't able to get its `navigationController`

Comment: Is your View Controller inside a NavigationViewController ? The navigationController property of a View Controller will return a valid navigation controller object only if the view controller is in a navigation controller's navigation stack

Comment: @thedjnivek it is, I checked before calling this method and the navigationController has a value.